# Using a Custom Tag Variable from Outside of a Custom Tag

Tags: coldfusion, custom-tag

Ok, I thought this would be simple but I'm getting an error telling me the variable does not exist.

Here is my custom tag code:

```
<cfset isBot = false>
<cfif find("bot", CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT)>
<cfset isBot = true>               
</cfif>
```

Here is my page calling the custom tag:

```
<cf_checkBot>
<cfif isBot> 
Yes This Is A Bot!
</cfif>
```

So how do I use a variable outside of a customtag that was set inside of a custom tag?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [the Caller scope](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=reuseCode_3.html#1122289):

```
<cfset isBot = false>
<cfif find("bot", CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT)>
<cfset Caller.isBot = true>               
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfset isBot = false>
<cfif find("bot", CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT)>
<cfset **caller.**isBot = true>               
</cfif>
```

You use the caller scope.

It might be better to use a function instead of a custom tag though.